# WPF UserControl Transition

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Main Window which has a Grid. On Button Click Events, I switch the children of the Grid between multiple UserControls. When I switch between these user controls I want to create a transition, something like fade or slide in etc. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Expression Blend, and either creating your own, or using pre-made visual transitions.

FluidMoveBehaviour is a common one for animating the removal and addition of objects to a content control. There are also some 'pseudo-3d' animations such as flip, rotate etc...

http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/DynamicLayoutTrans/